# Opening up dialog from MudAutocomplete and the list is still visible

Tags: c#, blazor, dialog, mudblazor

I have recreated the issue here: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkcdPFQrHgjgAXni

The issue is that I have a form on a Dialog which contains a MudAutoComplete. I have used the AfterItemsTemplate so that users have the option to add a new item to the list if they don't the item they want to select.

When this button is pressed (The add item button) the second dialog opens to add a new item. However, the MudAutoComplete list is still open and it covers the dialog that has just opened. I can still select an item from this list too which means that I can add an infinite amount of dialogs as the add button is still visible and working.

How can I hide this list after the second dialog is opened. Note that I don't want to close the original dialog.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Update: Found this https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/1342
But do not understand what to do still.

Comment: By "Note that I don't want to close the original dialog" do you mean the "FirstDialog" Component or the MudAutocomplete list?

Comment: The FirstDialog Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to close the MudAutocomplete component when opening the new Dialog

Set a reference to the MudAutocomplete component.

```
private MudAutocomplete<Element> _mudAuto = new MudAutocomplete<Element>();
```

and

```
<MudAutocomplete @ref="_mudAuto" ... >
```

Then use the method ToggleMenu to close it.

```
private void OpenDialog()
{
    _mudAuto.ToggleMenu();
    var options = new DialogOptions { CloseOnEscapeKey = true };
    DialogService.Show<DialogUsageExample_Dialog>("Simple Dialog", options);
}
```